# Hierarchy Custom Setting default value in Formula field taking the old value into calculation

Tags: formula-field, customsetting

I have a hierarchical custom setting called Test_Custom_Setting__c and I have field in there called Time_Delay__c set to the default value of 5 and also the Organizational defaults for this field is set to the value of 5 as well. The previous value for this field was 15.

Now I have used this custom setting field in a case formula field like below -

```
Date__c + (60-$Setup.Test_Custom_Setting__c .Time_Delay__c )/1440
```

And also tried checking the value for the custom field through apex-

```
Test_Custom_Setting__c tc = Test_Custom_Setting__c .getInstance();
Decimal def = tc.Time_Delay__c ;
System.debug(def);
```

Why is the formula field and the apex code taking the old value of the custom setting which is 15 and not the new value in both the scenarios mentioned above?

Please advise.

Comment: When you say `The previous value for this field was 15.` can you show or describe how/when this took place related to when the formula or apex reads occurred?

Comment: @MarkPond I just changed it manually based off business requirements. Even after the change it just takes the old value into the calculation on the formula field.

Comment: When you say default value, do you literally mean the field definitions default or do you mean a value set in the org level and other settings record?

Comment: @PhilW I meant the field definitions default value. This was working well with the previous setting, but now business needs a change to that value.

Comment: That is only used to set an initial value on creation of the containing record, so once created changing the default doesn't impact the record (since the field now has a value).

Comment: Oh is it. Then where are we doing this setting for the field to pull into formulas and from apex code? Also want to confirm, are you saying when the record is updated the formula field wont be taking the new value into the caluculations?

Comment: I just noticed that it is taking the user specific value for that field in the custom setting. How do we change it to take the organizational defaults into the calculations?

Comment: by definition, hierarchical custom settings use the user's value if present, else the profile's value if present, else the org value. Use custom metadata for org defaults

Comment: Thanks @cropredy it should be custom metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, [hierarchical custom settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cs_define.htm&type=5) ...

> Hierarchy—Uses a built-in hierarchical logic that lets you personalize settings for specific profiles or users. The hierarchy logic checks the organization, profile, and user settings for the current user and returns the most specific, or lowest, value. In the hierarchy, settings for an organization are overridden by profile settings, which, in turn, are overridden by user settings.

If you always want to use an org-level setting - make that setting a field in [Custom Metadata - which is also accessible in formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_formula_fields.htm&type=5)

```
Date__c + (60-$CustomMetadata.DateSettings__mdt.Test_Custom_Setting__c.Time_Delay__c )/1440
```

where

- `DateSettings__mdt` is the name of the custom metadata Sobject
- `Test_Custom_Setting__c` is the developerName of a specific record in the custom metadata
  `Time_Delay__c` is a field in the chosen record

Of course, you can use different names than the ones I chose based on your application